# R: cumsum and group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have the following sample data frame:

```r
dates <- c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-06", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-06")
group <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
values <- c(1, 5, 4, 2, 7, 3)

df <- data.frame(dates = as.Date(dates), group = group, values)
df
```

Can someone please tell me how I can compute a variable as the cumulated sum of `values` for each `group` (A and B) separately (+ chronologically)?

`values_cumulated` should be 1, 6, 10, 2, 9, 12

I was trying it with `group_by()` and `mutate(values_cum = cumsum(values) )` but couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% arrange(group, as.Date(dates)) %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(new = cumsum(values))`

Comment: See the linked FAQ for how to sum by group - you can replace `sum` with `cumsum`.